# NGX-Charts Color of nodes

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-charts

I'm trying to understand this 'simple' example of NGX-Charts:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-graph-simple-example

Each of the nodes in the graph has a different color, and if you look at the component.ts file, the node objects don't have a color field.

But the HTML template for each node uses:

```
<svg:rect [attr.width]="node.width" [attr.height]="node.height" [attr.fill]="node.options.color" />
```

Where's node.options.color coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of [@swimlane/ngx-graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@swimlane/ngx-graph) library used in the example, the `ngx-graph` template expects nodes of type `Node`. Now, looking at the [github code of this library](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph/), the type [Node](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph/blob/master/projects/swimlane/ngx-graph/src/lib/models/node.model.ts) is an interface with many additional properties.

The version of this library in the example is 4.1.1. This version is quite old as per their github repo, so I couldn't find the coe corresponding to the 4.1.1 version. I would suggest to use the latest version of the library and then you would be able to understand the properties used. Refer the github repo for a better understanding on these properties.